# Create PDF document from HTML form using Python

Tags: python, forms, pdf-generation

I’m looking to collect specific information through an online form that would be generated into a PDF template. Similar to a legal document.

For example:
Name, etc will be put in a specific section in the document

Are there any Python libraries that can help me with that?

Comment: Can be done with google forms and JavaScript scripting to google docs.

Comment: You might want to check out pypdf for a python library to create pdf's.

Comment: @user218076 It would be great if you could develop those comments into answers.

Answer (score 0):

If it suits your application to use an external web service, then you could call Docmosis.  You would create your document template in Word or Libre Office and upload it via the user-console or via code.  Then your Python application would call the service with the data collected in your online form to do the document generation - PDF in this case.

There is a code sample here showing how little Python code is required to create the PDF:  https://www.docmosis.com/resources/cloud/cloud-code-samples.html

Please note I work for Docmosis so am definitely biased.

I hope that helps.